# Setting up RewriteEngine and 301 redirect on .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I have this media wiki installation and I have since the beginning used rewrite engine on htaccess (as suggested [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache)) to redirect my site, for example (wiki.com) to (wiki.com/wiki/) with the code below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
```

But now I would like to add a separate 301 redirect of a directory from wiki.com/example to wiki.com/wiki/example while still keeping the original wiki rewrite

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 /example(.*) /wiki/example/$1
```

The problem is when I add that 301 redirect the whole site just goes kaput, I'm not experienced in the syntax at all so I have no idea how to couple the 2 bits while still keeping the site working.

Hope you can help me out with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/example(.*)$ /wiki/example/$1
```